# Update from cakephp 1.2 to cakephp 2.2.4

Tags: cakephp

I am using cakephp 1.2 up to now. Recently I decided to upgrade all my application from 1.2 to 2.2.4 (latest stable release). Anybody know how I could do this and what to change? Also I am using a single cake folder shared all the website (Advance installation).

Answer (score 2):

You should check out the migration guides for information on how to upgrade, what has changed, etc:

- http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices.html